# JSON data not being returned on firefox, IE Chrome are perfect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, google-chrome

So everything works fine on some computers. I get on my laptop > firefox > my website. Oh no the ajax request is returning the error '[object Object]'. I go into chrome and IE.....the JSON string returns "joe is the man from: JSON" in the alert just fine. I need to know if Jquery has a known issue handling JSON ? I can't have people hitting my page running into this random issue, considering that my cell phone's chrome returns the error '[object Object]'.

```
 <?php
//------------------------------The php file sending JSON
$results = array(
"price" => "joe is the man from: JSON",
);
print(json_encode($results));

?>



<script>
$.ajax({
    url: "myphpfile.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        alert(data.price);
    },
    error: function(error){
        alert(error);
    }
});
}
</script>
```

I also tried adding this to the PHP file just in case....same results:

```
  header('Content-type: application/json');
```

---

ok so i change it to this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "myphpfile.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        alert(data.price);
    },
   error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(status);
            alert(xhr.responseText);
            alert(xhr);
        }

     });
```

---

alert(status) - returned 'error'
alert(xhr.responseText); - returned a blank box
alert(xhr); - returned '[object Object]'

EDIT: This has stopped working on all browsers....

Comment: Is all of that code in a single file? If that's the case, then your `<script>` tag is going to show up as part of the json output, which FF will properly reject. A json response for an ajax call should contain the json text ONLY and NOTHING else.

Comment: no its just that way for you guys to view

Comment: `function( xhr,status,message) { alert(message) }` would be far more informative

Comment: let me add that in and post back with results, thanks

Comment: The value of `status` may also help, as well as `xhr.responseText`

Comment: "I need to know if Jquery has a known issue handling JSON ?"  no.

Comment: alert(status);  ---returned: "error"
alert(xhr.responseText); ---returned a blank box

Comment: i updated my main question with the responses

Comment: what did alert message give you? status giving you "error" doesn't make sense. it should be a number.

Comment: It literally gave me the text 'error' which I also thought was strange.

Comment: Have you checked the network tab in firebug?  Is the error occurring before the request is issued?  If not can you view the raw response text of the network request?  If so, what happens if you paste it as a string into the Firebug console and JSON.parse() it?

Comment: The response header is present before the first alert error: HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Date: Tue, 29 Oct 2013 20:36:16 GMT

Server: Apache/2.2.25 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.25 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 DAV/2 mod_bwlimited/1.4

X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.26

Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100

Connection: Keep-Alive

Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Content-Type: application/json

Comment: Stopped working on all browsers now, producing the same errors.

Comment: Protip: Use `console.log` instead of `alert`. It's **much** more informative

Comment: You can enable logging for AJAX in Firebug. Also, use console.log() instead of alert().

Comment: use console.log like all these other people are saying, it will be able to return `xhr` as an object instead of a string. But if you don't like that, at least do `alert(JSON.stringify(xhr))`

Comment: try: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: also try doing this in pure javascript: `var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();xhr.open('GET','myphpfile.php');xhr.send();xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){if(xhr.readyState===4){unjsonnedData=JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);alert(unjsonnedData.price}};xhr.onerror=function(e){console.log(e)}`

Comment: This pure javascript would not execute....I'm sensing that this may be the issue, I put an alert above the code and it will not fire unless i remove the xhr portion that you posted (even if the code is at the very top of the page)....why would this happen?

Comment: It would appear that JQuery versions are conflicting with each other, causing extreme behavior. When I go to the files manually vs include they function properly if I include JQuery 1.9 in that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that JQuery versions are conflicting with each other, causing extreme behavior. When I go to the files manually (vs include) they function properly. Although, I must include JQuery 1.9 in that header of that file.